# Forward Node to Translated Version with original friendly URL

Tags: 7, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

Here is the use case:

Node/View 1's path is "about-us" and it has language set to English.
Node/View 2's path is "acerca-de-nuestra-historia" and the language is set to Spanish.

I need a solution that will forward "es/about-us" to "es/acerca-de-nuestra-historia" and vice versa.

Am I missing something obvious? I can't seem to find a setting that does this with the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module.